# Adding headers for specific filetypes on k8s ingress

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I'm running nginx ingress and ingress controller on k8s. Need to add extra headers for specific filetypes (ie. http://blah/blah.pdf). The usual way (when not on k8s) to do things would be to leverage the `location` directive. However, running something as below on k8s adds extra location with no params, which is kinda expected, but results in ingress controller trying to serve the upstream from its local filesystem instead of a remote pod's:

The code:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  location ~* \.(pdf)$ {
             add_header a "b";
  }
```

The result:

```
            location ~* \.(pdf)$ {
                    add_header a "b";
            }

            location / {
            # some stuff
            }
```

Had a thought to add an extra rewrite below `add_header` directive, but that would cause an infinite redirection loop.

So let's take a step back. According to the docs, headers can be added in the following contexts: `http, server, location, if in location`:

- The first two are out of the question since I need to add headers only for specific filetypes, not globally.
- `Location` - as described above.
- Nested `location` - won't work on k8s.
- `If`? An approach that would be very far from perfect, nevertheless tried it and so far didn't work for me - after deployment, no proper code appears in ingress controller's nginx.conf (not sure why).

As of now I'm out of additional ideas. Hints would be greatly appreciated.

*edit:*
Seems that, when configured using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet`, `if` is properly added to `location` context. What I was trying previously was to use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet`, which yielded no results. Anyway, I've achieved a working config. The question whether this is an optimal one still remains open.